# Append the ID of div to URL so that the div is shareable

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {


  // global variables section
  var cards = document.querySelectorAll(".cards"); //capture all divs
  var crossButton = document.getElementsByClassName("back-button");
  var container = document.getElementsByClassName("cards-container");

  cards.forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener("click", function() { //click event listener
      cards.forEach(unclicked => {
        if (unclicked !== div) {
          unclicked.style.display = "none"; //disappear      elements that aren't clicked
        }

        //space for children elements variable container



        //tinker with functionalities here:
        container[0].style.overflowX = "hidden";
        crossButton[0].style.display = "block";
        div.style.margin = "2vh auto"; //make sure the div goes a little lower
        div.style.cursor = "auto"; //
        div.style.height = "65vh";
        div.style.width = "90vw";
        div.style.transition = "all 888ms ease-in-out";

        div.innerHTML = window.location.href + 'section';
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="cards-container">
  <div class="back-button">
    <img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/back.svg" alt="Back" class="back">
  </div>
  <!-- Individual cards section -->
  <div class="cards">
    <!-- Card-title -->
    <h2 class="title">Hanuman Statue</h2>
    <!-- Flexbox for image and content seperately -->
    <div class="flex-box">
      <div class="image-content">
        <img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/nasal_chowk.jpg" alt="Nasal Chowk" class="card-pic" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="hiddentitle">Hanuman Statue<br></h2>
        <p class="tag-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. . . . </p>


        <!-- Main body which appears on click -->
        <p class="main-body"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. .<br><br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-strip">
        <a href="../../../ASSETS/Visual/mohan-chowk.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/mohan-chowk.jpg" alt="" class="swipe"></a>
        <a href="../../../ASSETS/Visual/swet-bhairav-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/swet-bhairav-1.jpg" alt="" class="swipe"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Individual cards section -->
  <div class="cards">
    <!-- Card-title -->
    <h2 class="title">Hanuman Statue</h2>
    <!-- Flexbox for image and content seperately -->
    <div class="flex-box">
      <div class="image-content">
        <img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/nasal_chowk.jpg" alt="Nasal Chowk" class="card-pic" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="hiddentitle">Hanuman Statue<br></h2>
        <p class="tag-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. . . . </p>


        <!-- Main body which appears on click -->
        <p class="main-body"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. .<br><br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-strip">
        <a href="../../../ASSETS/Visual/mohan-chowk.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/mohan-chowk.jpg" alt="" class="swipe"></a>
        <a href="../../../ASSETS/Visual/swet-bhairav-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/swet-bhairav-1.jpg" alt="" class="swipe"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Individual cards section -->
  <div class="cards">
    <!-- Card-title -->
    <h2 class="title">Hanuman Statue</h2>
    <!-- Flexbox for image and content seperately -->
    <div class="flex-box">
      <div class="image-content">
        <img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/nasal_chowk.jpg" alt="Nasal Chowk" class="card-pic" />
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <h2 class="hiddentitle">Hanuman Statue<br></h2>
        <p class="tag-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. . . . </p>


        <!-- Main body which appears on click -->
        <p class="main-body"><br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. .<br><br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-strip">
        <a href="../../../ASSETS/Visual/mohan-chowk.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/mohan-chowk.jpg" alt="" class="swipe"></a>
        <a href="../../../ASSETS/Visual/swet-bhairav-1.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="My caption"><img src="../../../ASSETS/Visual/swet-bhairav-1.jpg" alt="" class="swipe"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to build a website in which a div gets larger on click. You could check the image below. There are many divs arranged like a card. [image: You could check the image below. There are many divs arranged like a card.] Now, I've created a Javascript function that is fired on click on any one of the divs. After the click function is fired, remaining divs disappear and the clicked one covers the screen.

Now, I want to make that div shareable, if it makes sense. When I open a div, is it possible to add an ID to URL so that users could share it? For instance, maybe, [www.xyz.com/palace#hanuman](http://www.xyz.com/palace#hanuman) or something like that. Also, of course the javascript that's fired on click has to be preserved.

Many thanks!

Comment: How would you want the user to get the URL, do they have to copy it or what?

Comment: Yes. Them copying the URL would be something that I am aiming for.

Comment: I'm sure you can find the copy and paste code on the sites you want to share to.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more? Copy and paste code on the sites as in?

Answer (score 2):

To do this would require you to:

1. Move the activating of the card to it's own function outside of the event listeners
2. Update the URL when a card is "active"
3. Update the URL when no card is no longer "active"
4. Activate a card if the page is visited with a 'search term'

Because the the activating of a card will need to be able to be triggered either by page load or click event. To reduce code repetition, this should be a separate function that can be invoked.

Also because of the phrasing of your question it is assumed you do not need to worry about other query search parameters already on your URL conflicting, so the example below is provided in a simplistic suggested solution to use ?searchterm=somestring style searching. So your users will be able to use URLs such as https://yoursite.com?desiredcard=watersprout

```
const updateURLSearchParams = function(cardNameAsString) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  params.set('desiredcard', cardNameAsString);

  params.toString(); 
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', `${location.pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
};

const removeSearchParams = function () {
  window.history.replaceState({}, '', '/'); // Will set to the root of your site i.e https://yoursite.com/ If you need a subpage instead change the last string parameter from '/' to '/subpageofyoursite/' which will replace the URL to https://yoursite.com/subpageofyoursite/
}


const activateCard = function(card) {
  updateURLSearchParams(card.name); // This will set the card.name to the url parameter desiredcard like so https://example.com?desiredcard=somecardname
  
  // Add code that makes card full screen here

}

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){ activateCard(e.target); });

eventThatClosesCard() { removeSearchParams }; // Remember to remove the search parameter when closing the card

window.onload = function() {
 const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
 if(searchParams.get('desiredcard')) { activateCard(searchParams.get('desiredcard')); }
}
```

This is very quickly written as an concept example for you to understand the approach and write a more efficient solution tailored to your codebase.

Comment: This makes so much sense! Thanks so much. I'll give it a try

Comment: @BibatshuThapaChhetri note that replaceState updates URL by overwriting the currentURL. This means the user can't use the browser back button to return to the previous state. The browser would navigate to the page before this page was visited.  >>  
If you would like the user to be able to use back to go back through the cards they have opened change the replaceState to pushState. The pushState function will update the URL in the same way without reloading the page. But by adding the updated URL as a new URL pushing what was the current URL to the history as a previously visited page.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function to your card select function:

```js
//text will be the part after the #
function setURL(text){
  //displayElement is the element that the user will highlight
  document.getElementById("displayElement").innerHTML = window.location.href + text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll give it a try and post the update here

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to work, and it makes sense too because the computer cannot find the link to open it. 

Here is the link: https://imgur.com/a/zUbbLtH

Comment: @BibatshuThapaChhetri Ok, it is time to start putting some code.

Comment: Do you want access to my code? If so, I'll post the imgur link for it too

Comment: @BibatshuThapaChhetri No, not in an image, directly into your question please.

Comment: Hi, I just did! I was refraining from doing so earlier because I am new and I don't have the best practices with naming or tidying my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to share to Facebook:

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* js/external.js */
let get, post, doc, htm, bod, nav, M, I, mobile, S, Q, aC, rC, tC, shuffle, rand, FBLoader; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
get = (url, success, context)=>{
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('GET', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  x.send();
}
post = function(url, send, success, context){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  const c = context || x;
  x.open('POST', url);
  x.onload = ()=>{
    if(success)success.call(c, JSON.parse(x.responseText));
  }
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      x.send(send);
    }
    else{
      const fd = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        fd.append(k, JSON.stringify(send[k]));
      }
      x.send(fd);
    }
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
doc = document; htm = doc.documentElement; bod = doc.body; nav = navigator; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
mobile = nav.userAgent.match(/Mobi/i) ? true : false;
S = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = (selector, within)=>{
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
aC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.add(...a);
  return aC;
}
rC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.remove(...a);
  return rC;
}
tC = function(){
  const a = [].slice.call(arguments), n = a.shift();
  n.classList.toggle(...a);
  return tC;
}
shuffle = array=>{
  let a = array.slice(), i = a.length, n, h;
  while(i){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*i--); h = a[i]; a[i] = a[n]; a[n] = h;
  }
  return a;
}
rand = (min, max)=>{
  let mn = min, mx = max;
  if(mx === undefined){
    mx = mn; mn = 0;
  }
  return mn+Math.floor(Math.random()*(mx-mn+1));
}
FBLoader = function(scriptURL = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0'){
  this.share = (url, size = 'large', layout = 'button_count')=>{
    const div = M('div'), data = div.dataset, link = M('div');
    div.className = 'hide fb-share-button'; data.href = url; data.layout = layout;
    data.size = size; link.className = 'fb-xfbml-parse-ignore'; 
    link.textContent = 'Share';
    link.onclick = ()=>{
      location = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?src=sdkpreparse&u='+encodeURIComponent(url);
    }
    div.appendChild(link);
    return div;
  }
  this.load = ()=>{
    const j = M('script'), s = S('script');
    j.src = scriptURL; s.parentNode.insertBefore(j, s);
  }
}
// magic under here - keep the above for ease of use
const fb = new FBLoader, out = I('output');
out.appendChild(fb.share('https://www.whitehouse.gov')); out.appendChild(M('br'));
out.appendChild(fb.share('https://www.fbi.gov')); fb.load();
}); // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* css/external.css */
*{
  box-sizing:border-box; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;
}
html,body,.main{
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' /><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />
    <title>Title Here</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='css/external.css' />
    <script src='js/external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'><div id='output'></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the facebook URL has an issue on Stack Overflow. Try this on localhost.